# What is the biblical defense for consubstantiation?

Tags: biblical-basis, communion, consubstantiation, real-presence, lollardism

I was studying various views on the Eucharist, and I found the view of Consubstantiation very interesting. I would like to know what arguments are used to defend this position.

---

**Consubstantiation**

> Consubstantiation is a Christian theological doctrine that (like transubstantiation) describes the real presence of Christ in the Eucharist. It holds that during the sacrament, the substance of the body and blood of Christ are present alongside the substance of the bread and wine, which remain present. It was part of the doctrines of Lollardy, {1} and considered a heresy by the Roman Catholic Church.[2] It was later championed by Edward Pusey of the Oxford Movement, and is therefore held by many high church Anglicans.[3][4] The Irvingian Churches (such as the New Apostolic Church) adhere to consubstantiation as the explanation of the real presence of Christ in the Eucharist.[5]

[Wikipedia - Consubstantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consubstantiation)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mauricio. Questions on here require evidence of some research that shows why there is a difficulty that the OP needs help with resolving. It's not for promoting any particular stance, or for debating a topic. Could you clarify whether it's purely Bible texts that are asked for, or if it's quotes from literature that explain the consubstantiation view (even if they don't include Bible references)?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is [*Christ's own words*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_of_Institution):

> Jesus took bread, and after blessing it broke it and gave it to the disciples, and said, "Take, eat; this is my body." <sup>27</sup>And He took a cup, and when He had given thanks He gave it to them, saying, "Drink of it, all of you, <sup>28</sup>for this is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many for the forgiveness of sins." (Matthew 26:26-28)

> He took bread, and after blessing it broke it and gave it to them, and said, “Take; this is my body.” <sup>23</sup>And He took a cup, and when He had given thanks He gave it to them, and they all drank of it. <sup>24</sup>And He said to them, "This is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out for many." (Mark 14:22-24)

> He took bread, and when He had given thanks, He broke it and gave it to them, saying, "This is my body, which is given for you. Do this in remembrance of me." <sup>20</sup>And likewise the cup after they had eaten, saying, "This cup that is poured out for you is the new covenant in my blood." (Luke 22:19-20)

[Transubstantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transubstantiation) (Roman Catholics),  [consubstantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consubstantiation) (Anglicans) and [sacramental union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramental_union) (Lutherans) are attempts to understand just what is meant by "this *is* my body/blood" when the elements still look, feel and taste like bread and wine.

To my knowledge, the nuances of these positions are generally extra-Scriptural. For a Roman Catholic who holds tradition in similar regard as Scripture, it is irrelevant that there is no *Scriptural* basis for their interpretation, while an Anglican or Lutheran might *reject* transubstantiation on the very basis of that lack of Scriptural support. Thus, the basis of these Protestant views might be regarded as "the best we can do from a Scripture which says almost nothing on the matter without resorting to extra-Scriptural teachings".

Comment: That's a fine answer from a non-Catholic perspective, but a Catholic would be apt to say that "this is my Body" _is_ the scriptural support for the doctrine.

Comment: @PeterTurner, but what *scripture* would this same (Roman) Catholic use to defend that their interpretation is more correct than the others? I don't know of any such, and *that* is my point. It's fine to say "the others are wrong", but what is the *scriptural* basis for saying that? Merely claiming 'the others aren't reading it right' doesn't really cut it. (If there *is* a scriptural case to be made, I'd love to know!)